# Offline WYSIWYG Mediawiki Editor for GitHub wikis

Tags: github, wiki, mediawiki

This is my first post, so please go easy on me if I say something stupid. Also please point me to the right direction of this question has been answered in any other places. I googled for this for a while but I did not get satisfactory answers.

I'm a big fan of GitHub and use it everyday to manage all my Open Source projects as well as paid subscription for the company that work for. I use the wiki heavily to make documentations and edit most of the contents offline with text editors and push it in git interface of the wiki.

I was wondering if there are any good offline and desktop based app that you could recommend that could help me speedup my workflow by providing a graphical WYSIWYG editor. I could just load up the file and edit it in a word processor like interface and push it in git. I don't want any solution that required a local server setup like apache, that would be overkill and there is already a web based editor in the GitHub wiki. Anything that runs on Linux or Mac OS X would be a good one for me.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** While GitHub wikis are by default powered by *Markdown*, we use *Mediawiki* syntax, so I would be interested in Mediawiki graphical editor.

Comment: This would probably be a good question for softwarerecommendations.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Wikis are Markdown based, I personally just use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) with a Markdown syntax highlighter, while you don't get the same result (since it's not rendering the HTML/CSS), you get a "feel" for the text and how it's going to look. This just allows you to focus on writing.

If your on Windows, there are plenty of other Markdown plugins for the common text editors (I've used [this](https://github.com/thomsmits/markdown_npp) for Notepad++ in the past).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Rob, while I really love Markdown, for the works in my office we are using  Mediawiki syntax. I just found that there are Mediawiki syntax bundle for Textmate as well, I have to give it a try and see if that works for me.

Comment: Just tried the _Markdown_ and _Mediawiki Bundle_. I realized that _Markdown_ bundle has a preview generator, which is really good, and [Mediawiki Bundle](https://github.com/textmate/mediawiki.tmbundle), while not giving any preview, is decent. These two will do for the time being, unless someone has the links for a full fledged Graphical Editor. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

if you are a mac user [MouApp](http://mouapp.com/) works best

Comment: Wow, this one is perfect for markdown. I certainly hope they'd come up with one for mediawiki as well :)